# Getting scrollTop value while doing a scroll to top animation

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I want to be able to keep track of the current scrollTop value while a `scrollTop: 0` animation is running. Is this possible at all?

Doing the good old:

```
$('.overflowingelement').animate({
  scrollTop: 0
},500, function() {
  console.log(scrollTop());
});
```

Won't help as the callback is fired when the animation is done. Are there some way around this?

Comment: What do you mean with 'keep track of the current scrollTop value'. You mean stop it when you scroll your mousewheel while it is animated?

Comment: @LGVentura I'm moving around another element based on the `scrollTop` value and as it doesn't change while animating, this element doesn't move as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `step:function(){` callback of `animate()`:

```
$('.overflowingelement').click(function(){
    $('.overflowingelement').animate({scrollTop:'0px'}, {duration:500, step: function(){
        $('span').html($('.overflowingelement').scrollTop());
    }, complete:function(){
        $('span').html($('.overflowingelement').scrollTop()); 
    }
    });
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/aDkE6/